# TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype and format specifier. How to save a dataframe with different value types as a txt file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, save

I have a dataframe with 10 columns that each columns contains values different types:
int,str,str,int,float,float,float,float,float,float

I want to save my df as a txt file. I use this code:

`fmt = '%5f','%5s','%5s','%5f','%8.3f','%8.3f','%8.3f','%8.4f','%8.4f','%8.4f'`
`np.savetxt(r'C:\Users\np.txt', df.values, fmt=fmt, delimiter="")`

but I get this error:

> Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%5f%5s%5s%5f%8.3f%8.3f%8.3f%8.4f%8.4f%8.4f')

Seems that it needs the same format for each value.

Is there any way to save my dataframe as a text file?

The format of values is too important for me. Sadly, to_csv will lose the format.

Thanks in advance

Mehrnoosh

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not just calling df.to_csv?

Comment: yes, I need to use the output file as an input for simulation software it reads only a text file.

Comment: to_csv can save as a .txt file as well. just pass the file name to the method, and the text should be saved exactly as it appears in the dataframe

Comment: Thanks. When I use to_csv, the .txt file loses the format (fmt). What are the options to save the format exactly?

Comment: Just what is `df.values`?  Shape, and dtype for a start.  The error implies it is `object` dtype.  All `savetxt` is doing is:  `fmt%tuple(row)` for each "row" of `df.values` (plain  python string formatting)  Something about that `values` array is not compatible with the `fmt` string you specify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error raise if the **format is not correctly specified for the original type of the column**. Consider the following example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {
    'col_str': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'col_float': [1.5, 2.5, 0.7]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df
```

then if I try to save `col_str` with a float format and the `col_float` with a string format a `TypeError` will raise

```
fmt = ['%5f', '%5s']
np.savetxt(r'test.txt', df.values, fmt=fmt, delimiter="")
>>> TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%5f%5s')
```

otherwise if the formats are correctly specified it will work

```
fmt = ['%5s', '%.2f']
np.savetxt(r'test.txt', df.values, fmt=fmt, delimiter="")
```

Comment: Thank you. I changed the "int" format in my original dataframe to "float" and it worked! Although the numbers are actually integers and it doesn't make any sense to me.